# How is the Material-UI website creating a drop-down select in it's AppBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I'm having trouble doing the same with my app. I've added a Select component, but it doesn't render correctly. Should I be using a different nested component to create this?

[image]

I cannot see an example in material-UI's documentation. I am not sure of the correct styles to use. I am using a Select component here, but I'm not sure if its the same the Material UI website is using as it doesn't seem to inherit the correct style. It would be great if someone can point me to the correct method of adding a drop-down to the Toolbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That "dropdown" is actually composed of [Button Component](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons) and [Menu Component](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menus).

The docs site is open-sourced and you can check the implementation [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/docs/src/modules/components/AppFrame.js#L220).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for pointing out that the actual site is open-sourced. Very useful.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, how nice to be live in an open-source world. :)